# Set initial app view - Chrome App/Electron/JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, electron

How can I set the inital zoom for my app. Currently it loads at 100% zoom I want it to load at 80% zoom. Also is there a way to load full screen instead of having to specify width/height?

main.js

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
let mainWindow;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  app.quit();
});

app.on('ready', function() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 1600, height: 900 });
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/main.html');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`BrowserWindow`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/), there're many properties you can configure when create BrowserWindow.

- Zoom: `zoomFactor`
- Fullscreen: `fullscreen`

So just use `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ fullscreen: true, zoomFactor: 0.8 });`

Comment: Cheers Buddy! :)